# How to find if dates not found in table

Tags: php, laravel

```php
$gno = head::select('point','DATE')
            ->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
            ->orderBy('DATE','desc')
            ->get();
```

This code I have used to get past seven days of records from current date but if the date is not found in the table I want to return `0`.

I don't know how to achieve this, any help?

Comment: You are not returning anything with this code. How are you using these results? Where exactly do you want to return `0`?

Comment: I dont to check $gno empty or not i want to check date of records . my $gno returns like [{"point":"SRT-400","DATE":"2021-06-18 00:00:00"},{"point":"SRT-394","DATE":"2021-06-18 00:00:00"} i only have records in date 18. I want to return 0 for other dates like [{"point":"0","DATE":"0"}]

Answer (score 3):

You can change your query to use [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist).

```php
$gno = head::select('point','DATE')
            ->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
            ->orderByDesc('DATE')
            ->exists();
```

This way you get either `true` or `false`.

If you want to get the records and return them if found or return `0` if there are none, you have to do this:

```php
$gno = head::select('point','DATE')
            ->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
            ->orderByDesc('DATE')
            ->get();

return $gno->isNotEmpty() ? $gno : 0;
```

Comment: if  no records found   I want to return  0  By Each date

Comment: Then try my second code, the one I use with `isNotEmpty`

Comment: I dont to check $gno empty or not  i want to  check  date  of records . my $gno returns like [{"point":"SRT-400","DATE":"2021-06-18 00:00:00"},{"point":"SRT-394","DATE":"2021-06-18 00:00:00"} i only have records in  date 18. I want to return 0 for other dates like [{"point":"0","DATE":"0"}]

Comment: You are only going to return existing data... You will have to manipulate your data with PHP to accomplish that... Your question is not clear, but I understand your comment here, so update it with that example

Comment: please give proper title  i will change

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate each date in PHP and then go through it and get all items for that date:

```
$gno = head::select('point','DATE')
    ->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
    ->orderBy('DATE','desc')
    ->get();
$dates = collect(range(0,7))->mapWithKeys(function ($i) use ($gno) {
   $date = Carbon::now()->subDays($i);
   return [ $date->toDateString() => $gno->filter(function ($head) use ($date) {
      return $date->isSameDay($head->DATE);
   }) ];
});
```

This should return a collection with dates as keys and a collection of rows as values with the collection being empty if there are no items for that date.

Comment: return [ $date->toDateString() =>$gno->filter(function ($head) {

          return $date->isSameDay($head->DOCDATE); This two rows shows error $gno and $date not defined

Comment: @Gopalkrish forgot to add `use`

Comment: how to import ?